# Binding gitea to the localhost address for tunneling?

Tags: git, go, ssh, gitea

I've found some configuration which appears to indicate the port the gitea binds to, see below:

[image: hos]

I changed the actual address of the machine to `127.0.0.1` (the loopback) thinking that I would be able to make [gitea accessible only by tunneling into the device with SSH](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106333/is-binding-all-private-services-to-the-127-0-0-1-address-and-then-accessing-them), but when I restart the service I can still access it via the device's ip on port 3000.

Shouldn't changing the `ROOT_URL` and `HTTP_PORT` cause it to be bound to the loopback address, requiring me to do port forwarding through my SSH client to reach port `http://127.0.0.1:3000`?

P.S. If you feel this question does not belong on Stack Exchange, go ahead and send it over to another site that is more well suited to it; but I would think that gitea isn't used too much by people other than programmers, which is why I posted it here.

Comment: I like how you censured the private IP address 192.168.x.x ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To double-check that Gitea is *actually* listening only on the loopback interface, check the output of

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 3000
```

which should appear as `127.0.0.1:3000` (in the 3rd column). Any other binding would indicate that your changes to the config haven't affected the service, and that it's still binding to other interfaces.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to use IPv6....binding to any and all addresses `::`

Comment: Had to use the `HTTP_ADDR` configuration directive it seems...

Answer (score 1):

Just repeating what @leeand00 says: gitea's config lists `HTTP_ADDR` as the relevant setting. https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/config-cheat-sheet/

Afterwards, `netstat -tulpn | grep 3000` is certainly a good check to see if everything is right :)